# Generate next lexicographical string in Haskell

Tags: string, algorithm, haskell, combinations

If I was given a string like `skhfbvqa`, how would I generate the *next* string? For this example, it would be `skhfbvqb`, and the next string of that would be `skhfbvqc`, and so on. The given string (and the answer) will always be *N* characters long (in this case, *N=8*).

**What I tried:**

I tried to generate the entire (infinite) list of possible combinations, and get the required (next) string of the given string, but unsurprisingly, it's so slow, that I don't even get the answer for *N=6*.

I used list comprehension:

```
allStrings = [ c : s | s <- "" : allStrings, c <- ['a'..'z'] ]

main = do
    input <- readFile "k.in"
    putStrLn . head . tail . dropWhile (not . (==) input) . map reverse $ allStrings
```

(Please excuse my incredibly bad Haskell-ing :) Still a noob)

So my question is, how can I do this? If there are multiple methods, a comparison between them is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Scanning `allStrings` looks incredibly inefficient -- it is similar to computing the successor by `\x -> head . tail $ dropWhile (/= x) [0..]`. It works, but requires exponential time/space. I'd instead represent the string as a backwards list, and perform standard "addition with carry" on each char/digit. This would have linear worst-case complexity, as expected. (Further, it's also amortized constant time, since the geometric sum converges, hence kind-of optimal)

Comment: @chi Yep, `allStrings` _is_ extremely inefficient. That's just the first thing that came into my mind. Your suggestion sounds very interesting. Can you please provide that as an answer but with a few more pointers/steps?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version with base conversion (this way you could add and subtract arbitrarily if you like):

```hs
encode x base = encode' x [] where
  encode' x' z | x' == 0 = z
               | otherwise = encode' (div x' base) ((mod x' base):z)

decode num base =
  fst $ foldr (\a (b,i) -> (b + a * base^i,i + 1)) (0,0) num
```

Output:

```hs
*Main> map (\x -> toEnum (x + 97)::Char) 
       $ encode (decode (map (\x -> fromEnum x - 97) "skhfbvqa") 26 + 1) 26

"skhfbvqb"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So this is like considering the string as a base-26 number, right? With characters `[a-z]` instead of digits.

Comment: @Roshnal Yes, exactly - it's like considering the string as a base-26 number, with characters `[a-z]` instead of digits.

Comment: @Roshnal it might require some padding for strings that have `a`s (considered zeros) as prefixes

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. Interesting approach, will try this out as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go and make a helper function `f :: Integer -> String` and one `g :: String -> Integer`, where `f 1 = "a"`, ... `f 27 = "aa"`, `f 28 = "ab"` and so on and the inverse `g`.

Then `incrementString = f . succ . g`

Note: I omitted the implementation of `f` on purpose for learning

### Update

for a different approach you could define a increment with carry function `inc' :: Char -> (Char, Bool)`, and then

```
incString :: String -> String
incString = reverse . incString'
   where incString' [] = []
         incString' (x:xs) = case inc' x of (x',True) -> x': incString' xs
                                            (x',False) -> x':xs
```

Note: this function is not tail recursive!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn't think of it that way; will try it! However I'm wondering if this can be done in a more "Haskell-y" way (like with built-in functions, monads, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work. It just uses pattern matching to see if the string begins with a **z** and adds an additional **a** accordingly.

```
incrementString' :: String -> String
incrementString' []          = ['a']
incrementString' ('z':xs)    = 'a' : incrementString' xs
incrementString' (x:xs)      = succ x : xs

incrementString :: String -> String
incrementString = reverse . incrementString' . reverse
```

Comment: This looks very good to me. Check if `incrementString "zzzzzzzz"` is what you really want -- I mention this since you wrote that the length of the answer must be 8.

Comment: @chi You're correct, there's an issue there. It gives the output of 9 a's... But I meant that the question-provider (this is part of a bigger exercise question) has mentioned that the answer will be N digits. Reading my question again, it appears that I might have been a little bit unclear. Sorry :/